# Kentico - BizForm File Field Attachment/Upload URL

Tags: asp.net, kentico

For a BizForm field of type `File` using an `Upload file` control, the recorded submission data for the field is being saved as a string similar to a value of `a858eda6-4699-4bda-81d0-1b85d69aa9a7.pdf/test.pdf` for a PDF with a name of `test.pdf` with a field with a code name of `Foo`. I am trying to get the URL for that uploaded document for a given BizForm submission. Trying to access the attachment using the following URLs result 404 errors:

```
https://somesite.com/getattachment/a858eda6-4699-4bda-81d0-1b85d69aa9a7.pdf/test.pdf
https://somesite.com/getattachment/a858eda6-4699-4bda-81d0-1b85d69aa9a7.pdf/test.pdf.aspx
https://somesite.com/CMSPages/GetFile.aspx?guid=a858eda6-4699-4bda-81d0-1b85d69aa9a7
```

How can the URL be built to access a given BizForm submission's `File` field that uses the `Upload file` control for a field with a code name of `Foo`? And/or how can be accessed from code behind if I know the BizForm submission's ID in something like a `BizFormItemEvents.Insert.After` handler.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
    https:`//somesite.com/CMSPages/GetBizFormFile.aspx?filename=a858eda6-4699-4bda-81d0-1b85d69aa9a7.pdf`

you can try macro like:

```
{%  
row = Siteobjects.Forms["FormCodeName"].Items.Where("ItemId = 123").FirstItem;
row["attachmentFieldname"]
#%}
```

Here is an old link to [work with biz form files](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-api-to-work-with-bizform-files), most of it is still valid. it will give some ideas. Here is a link to [GetBizFormFile.aspx.cs](https://github.com/KuduApps/Kentico/blob/master/CMSModules/Bizforms/CMSPages/GetBizFormFile.aspx.cs)

Using [API](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/form-data) it should pretty straight forward:

```
var filepath =  BizFormItemProvider.GetItems(formClassName)
.Where("itemid = 123")
.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().GetValue("FileField")
```

You will get the same format: `<GUID>.<extension>/<orig_name>.<extension>`. Then you can parse and make URL out of it `~/CMSPages/GetBizFormFile.aspx?filename=<GUID>.<extension>`

Comment: Thanks for your help!